# Failing to add object in main and getting null pointer exception

Tags: java, object, nullpointerexception

So I have this class called Celula,
which creates cells of a linked lists with an element and a method to get next cell.

```
public class Celula {
private Celula proxima;

private Object elemento;

public Celula(Celula proxima, Object elemento) {
    this.proxima = proxima;
    this.elemento = elemento;
}

public Celula(Object elemento) {
    this.elemento = elemento;
}

public void setProxima(Celula proxima) {
    this.proxima = proxima;
}

public Celula getProxima() {
    return proxima;
}

public Object getElemento() {
    return elemento;
}
```

}

I am calling this method to add the element in the last cell

```
    public void adicionaNoFim(Object elemento) {
    if(elemento != null){
        ultima.getElemento();
    }
}
```

I am adding the object in main like this:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {

    listaEncadeada lista = new listaEncadeada();

    lista.adicionaNoFim("Paulo");
    lista.adicionaNoFim("Roberto");

    System.out.println(lista);
}
```

But I get a null pointer exception.
I don't understand why it is null if I am adding a value to it.

Comment: p.s: method "adicionaNoFim" is in class "listaEncadeada"

Comment: Please, edit your post with the [stack trace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace).

Comment: without stacktrace it's difficult to say: e.g. could be `ultima` that's null but you didn't post the source of `listaEncadeada`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that nothing is setting the `ultima` variable.

This means that `ultima` is the initial value, `null` when the `adicionaNoFim` method is called.

null.anything() will cause a null pointer exception.